# while summing of column and joining two tables returns double count

Tags: sql, sum, inner-join

I have two table and i have performed inner joined on them:
Below is my query

```
SELECT a.ship_id AS ship_id,
       sum(a.qty) as total_qty
from table_a as a
inner join table_b on a.shp_id = b.shpid
group by a.shp_id

Sample data:

table_a
-----------------------------
product_name | qty | ship_id
-----------------------------
item_1       | 10  | 1
item_2       | 20  | 1
item_3       | 10  | 2
item_4       | 10  | 2

table_b
-------------------
ship_id | desc
-------------------
1       | desc_1
2       | desc_2
```

What i am getting output of above query is as follows:

```
--------------------
ship_id | total_qty
--------------------
1       | 60
2       | 40
```

Expected output:

```
--------------------
ship_id | total_qty
--------------------
1       | 30 
2       | 20
```

Can anyone please help me how to get this.

Comment: Your query looks fine and on the data you have provided should return the results you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below way -

```
select a.ship_id,totalqty
from
(SELECT ship_id AS ship_id,
       sum(qty) as totalqty
from table_a group by ship_id) as a
inner join table_b on a.shp_id = b.shpid
```

Comment: @MiteshBhanushali, join without aggregation is duplicating your row since there is no reference of item in ship table. That's why you need to do aggregation in first table then join with the 2nd table.